# Does onReceive of BroadcastReceiver run concurrently?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm learning Android application.
 there's something I wanna ask you guys.

If I have to notify a certain broadcast receiver several times in a row,
 can its onReceive method be invoked before it finished previous task?
 if so, does it perform its task normally?

thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor sorry, but I haven't. source I fix is seriously huge, so I just ask helps before I make any changes.

Comment: as BroadcastReceiver runs in ui thread there's no race condition, however remember that each onReceive is called in new instance of BroadcastReceiver - you can check it by logcating THIS in receiver like: @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { Log.d(TAG, "" + this); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It runs in main thread so no race conditions. However you can use registerReceiver to pass a Handler to receive onReceive in non UI thread http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver, android.content.IntentFilter, java.lang.String, android.os.Handler)

Comment: Question is can onReceive process broadcast ,if already a broadcast is in process.if so then what will happen to broadcast in process

Comment: the second broadcast would be a new one ofcourse, not related with the previous one

Comment: that means it will execute both of them one after another or simultaneously...Dont take it as i m pulling ur leg.I m just curious to know

Comment: @PulkitSethi thank for your answer. "It runs in main thread so no race conditions." means there's queue or something for BroadcastReceiver to handle simulataneous broadcast messages in order?